# knockout, whats the best way to find a value in observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an observableArray,  I have a name "Zippy", I need to check if it is in the array. if this name exists, I need to get its type.  how should I do that?

```
// This observable array initially contains three objects
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this, you can use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` function for checking an element with your custom logic..

```
var name = "Zippy";
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(anotherObservableArray(), function(item) {
    return item.name == name;
});

var type;

if(match)
   type = match.type
```

Comment: hi, Yograj, I have another question. if I want to change the value of an existing item in the array, how should I do it?  I post my question here, can you please take a look?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163322/knockoutjs-how-do-you-upate-value-in-observablearray

Comment: so isn't this wrong in that it should be item.name() and not item.name

Comment: @Seabizkit Yes I can confirm it should be `item.name()`. I copied the code directly and got `undefined` until I accessed the actual data in the observable. Good code otherwise.